# Catch exceptions with decorator and continue

Tags: python, exception, logging, decorator

I'm trying to log and process exceptions in a decorator function and then continue the execution of the code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from functools import wraps

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def logger(func):
    async def exception_handler(*arg, **kwargs):
        try:
            await func(*arg, **kwargs)
        except Exception as err:
            log.error(f"Exception occured: {err}")
            # Send log to external system
    return exception_handler


@logger
async def bad_division(dividend, divisors):
    for divisor in divisors:
        print(dividend / divisor)
    print("How do I continue?")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dividend  = 10
    divisors = [2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 0]
    asyncio.run(bad_division(dividend, divisors))
```

Is it possible to continue to iterate through the `for loop` without wrapping `print(dividend / divisor)` in `try catch`?

Comment: Looks like a job for a context manager, like `with log_exceptions(): print(dividend / divisor)`

Comment: you have to use `try/except` or `if divisor != 0:` with this single line. But you can't do this with decorator. Decorator can't wrap single line inside function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's elaborated, inefficient and/or bad practice, but I think I have a solution for you are searching for (Me too I'd like to have a better answer).

The idea is to divide the code into "paragraphs" and set a couple of counters, so that the paragraphs which have been successfully `try`ed can go on, and the exception are retried skipping already completed paragraphs.

This is the decorator of a class method that you use to perform your operation

```
def handler_for_run(run):
    def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
        this = args[0] # It's the "self"        

        while this.error_counter < 2:
            print(f"Let's try again: a={this.error_counter}")
            try:
                run(*args, **kwargs)
                break # Ok, exiting the for loop
                
            except Exception as e:                
                print(f"When trying paragraph {this.paragraph_number}: {type(e).__name__}: {e}")
                this.error_counter += 1
                #print(f"{this.paragraph_number} KO, a={this.error_counter}")
                this.todo = this.paragraph_number # This is where we successfully arrived
                this.paragraph_number = 0 # Let's recheck from beginning

    return inner_function
```

This is the class defining the counters

class Operations:

```
def __init__(self, title=None):
    self.paragraph_number = 0
    self.todo = 0
    self.error_counter = 0
    self.title = f"Paragraph {self.paragraph_number}: {title}"


def paragraph(self, title=""):
    is_todo = self.paragraph_number == self.todo
    if is_todo:
        print(f"Paragraph {self.paragraph_number}: {title}")
        self.todo += 1
    else:
        print("already done")
        self.error_counter = 0
        
    self.paragraph_number += 1
    return is_todo
```

And in this other decorated method you do your operations

```
@handler_for_run
def numeri(self, a,b,c,d,e,f):

        if self.paragraph("first"):
            print(f"Result = {a*a}")

        if self.paragraph("second"):
            print(f"Result = {b*b}")

        if self.paragraph("third"):
            print(f"Result = {c*c}") # this will fail

        if self.paragraph("fourth"):
            print(f"Result = {d*d}")

        if self.paragraph("fifth"):
            print(f"Result = {e*e}")  # this will fail

        if self.paragraph("sixth"):
            print(f"Result = {f*f}")
```

I instanciate the class and I call the decorated class:

```
o = Operations()
o.numeri(1, 2, "asd", 4, "qwe", 6)
```

The result:

```
Let's try again: a=0
Paragraph 0: first
Result = 1
Paragraph 1: second
Result = 4
Paragraph 2: third
When trying paragraph 3: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
Let's try again: a=1
already done
already done
already done
Paragraph 3: fourth
Result = 16
Paragraph 4: fifth
When trying paragraph 5: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
Let's try again: a=1
already done
already done
already done
already done
already done
Paragraph 5: sixth
Result = 36
```